# How can i edit an existing Typo3 Extension (Backend Configuration Page)?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

i want to edit an existing Typo3 Backend configuration page.
[I want to edit a configuration page like this here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57wYc.png)

Where can i edit the extensions backend?
To be more clear: where can i change the edit page that an editor can use to change content.

Can someone give me a hint to the right directory or file in generall?

I'm using Typo3-7.6

Thanks

Comment: Off topic: I recommend to update to the current version of TYPO3 CMS 10. TYPO3 CMS 7.6 is no longer supported!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, can't manage to put all questions in an unformatted comment.

there are a lot of questions, as you are not clear what you want. Maybe that is a problem of the correct words, the vocabluary, but in TYPO3 we have some fix terms for specific object. And I think you do not handle these terms according to the TYPO3 community.

let's define some terms:

first the concept of TYPO3:
all data is stored in record of differnt database tables. All records are organized with some fields and teh main field is `uid`, the unique ID.
the main table is `pages` according to the folders of your disk. those folders can contain other records (like files). (nearly) each record in TYPO3 has a relation to a `pages`record ina field named `pid`. even `pages`records have this field and so they build a tree of pages and subpages.
There is one special `page`, which is no real page: the page with the ' uid' zero. As there is no real `pages`record with the `uid`zero, there are other records with are stored in that page by having a `pid` zero. for example the start of your page tree is anchored in page zero, or global records like languages, user, storages.

Aside of being the anchor to other records, the `pages`records have information themself. (page name, kind of page, a teaser image, SEO-information, visibility, accessibility, ...)

your screenshot looks like a content record (normaly in the table `tt_content`), in the lower right corner there you can see the table name and the `uid`the the currently edited record.

'Backend': with `backend` we name the view to the data where an editor can change the content of the website.  The real website is the frontend. This can be seen by everyone without the need to login in the `backend` (you might have access-restriccted areas of your website which need a login, but that still is 'frontend' as there is no option to edit content.

in the backend the editor might be restricted what he can access and what he can modify. An `admin`user has no restriction (up until version 9 where the role of a maintainer occured to manage more general and basic options)

so we have not a single '**backend configuration page**' but multiple places where we could configure special aspects of the website.

also there is no special '**extension backend**'. we have global extension configuration and records belonging to an extension. (And an extension can enhance existing records with additional fields.)

Please be more specific what you want to change

Comment: Hello Mr. Wilke, im sorry but I'm at the very start of learning typo3. What i need to do is: Add a Checkbox in the Content Record and save the Checkbox as a bool-value in the DB. I've found the File to configer this "Edit Record"-Page here: xyzExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/xyz.html 
It is build with flux, so now i know where to change the "Edit Record"-Page to change the Options of the Extension. Now i need to find out how to save that new Checkbox in the DB and do something with it in the Frontend of the Extension.

Comment: you should learn how to build an extension, where you can add further fields in the database and in the record. not only to show the field but building getter and setter to exchange the information with the database. (if the origin is an extbase table)